# Json parse returning null arrays in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to parse a json and return its values in an array, then I want to show it in a listview, the log shows me the result that I want, but it is not showing in my cellphone, I'm missing something that I don't know.

The function that make the SyncTask:

```
   public class SincronizarTask {
    private Activity ctx;
    public SincronizarTask(Activity applicationContext) {
        this.ctx = applicationContext;
    }

    public void inicia(){
        this.syncClientes();
    }

    private void syncClientes() {
        ClientRest mClientesRest = new ClientRest(ctx);
        mClientesRest.getClientes(new ClientRest.ClientesRestListener() {
            public void clientesReceived(List<ClientesModel> clientes) {
                for (int i = 0; i < clientes.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(clientes.get(i).getNome());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ClienteActivity:

```
public class ClienteActivity extends SherlockFragment {
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cliente, container, false);
        try {
            ClienteViewAdapter ad = new ClienteViewAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_cliente_item);
            ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listaClientes);

            lv.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
            lv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                   // TextView clienteId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.clienteId);
                    TextView clienteNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.clienteNome);
                    TextView clienteTipoPessoa = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.clienteTipo);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ContatosView.class);
                    //intent.putExtra("id_cliente", clienteId.getText()); // envia o id do cliente para a tela de detalhes
                    intent.putExtra("nome", clienteNome.getText());
                    intent.putExtra("tipo_pessoa", clienteTipoPessoa.getText());

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            lv.setAdapter(ad);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Erro").setMessage(e.getMessage()).setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            }).show();
        }
        return view;
    }
```

ClienteViewAdapter:

```
public class ClienteViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ClientesModel> {
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final int resourceId;

    public ClienteViewAdapter(FragmentActivity context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.resourceId = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        ClientesModel cliente = getItem(position);

        view = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);

        //TextView tvId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        TextView tvNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.clienteNome);
        TextView tvTipo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.clienteTipo);

        //tvId.setText(String.valueOf(cliente.ge()));
        tvNome.setText(cliente.getNome());
        tvTipo.setText(cliente.getTipo_pessoa());

        return view;
    }
}
```

ClientRest:

```
        JsonObjectRequest mJsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                List<ClientesModel> clientes = null;
                try {
                    clientes = parseJSON(response);
                    pDialog.hide();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                listener.clientesReceived(clientes);
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                    pDialog.hide();
                }
                error.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        ) 

        mRequestQueue.add(mJsonObjectRequest);
    }

    private List<ClientesModel> parseJSON(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
        try {
            JSONArray dados = json.getJSONArray("dados");

            for (int i = 0; i < dados.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject item = dados.getJSONObject(i);

                ClientesModel mClientesModel = new ClientesModel();
                ClientesContatosModel mClientesContatoModel = new ClientesContatosModel();

                /* cadastra os dados necessários no objeto no modelo */
                mClientesModel.setId(item.optInt("id"));
                mClientesModel.setNome(item.optString("nome"));
                mClientesModel.setTipo_pessoa(item.optString("tipo_pessoa"));
                mClientesModel.setInformacoes_adicionais(item.optString("informacoes_adicionais"));
                mClientesModel.setCpf(item.optString("cpf"));
                mClientesModel.setCnpj(item.optString("cnpj"));
                JSONArray contatos = item.getJSONArray("contatos");
                for (int j = 0; j < contatos.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject data = contatos.getJSONObject(j);

                    mClientesContatoModel.setNome(data.optString("nome"));

                    mClientesContatoModel.setCargo(data.optString("cargo"));

                }

                arrNews.add(mClientesModel);
                arrContatos.add(mClientesContatoModel);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arrNews;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip for you:  Boil your problem down to a SSCCE: http://sscce.org.  You are much more likely to get help that way.  Not many people are going to take the time to go through the 100's of lines of code you have posted.

Comment: @EJK I've shortened the code can you help me now?